# Auto shut down for KDB instance

Tags: kdb

I am trying to set an auto shutdown on a KDB instance 24 hours after the launch.

I have been playing around with the `.z.exit` and `\t` but could not figure it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the timer function `.z.ts` (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zts-timer) which is triggered at each interval set by `\t` to terminate the q process using `exit` (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/exit/), e.g.

```
q) set timer to 24 hours (milliseconds)
q)\t 24*60*60*1000
q).z.ts:{exit 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

On startup you could define your start time, then set a timer to check if the current time is 24 hours later and then exit.

```
startTime:.z.P;
.z.exit:{"Whatever you want to happen on exit"};
.z.ts:{if[1D<.z.P-startTime;exit 0]};
system"t 60000"; /set timer to whatever frequency
```

Comment: Perfect that works too. Thanks ! Any idea how I can pass those as command line arguments?

Comment: Pass which exactly? You couldn't really pass code as a command line arg